# Est-ce que ce message vous semble naturel ou un peu bizarre?

Tags: usage, formulation-idiomatique, politesse, correspondance, email

Est-ce que ce message vous semble naturel ou un peu bizarre?

---

Cher Monsieur,

Je vous remercie de l’attention portée à ma candidature et me tiens à votre entière disposition pour tout complément d'information.

Bien cordialement,

Comment: [Please consider reading what the site is about](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). 

We are not a text translation or proofreading service. If you're asking about the correctness of a sentence, tell us which **specific** word or construction you are unsure about.

Comment: Tout me semble parfaitement correct.

Answer (score 1):

Il y a deux problèmes, dans la formule d'appel et dans  la formule de politesse à la fin. Celui de la fin n'est pas aussi clairement tranché.

1/ La formule d'appel n'est pas standard ; « Monsieur, » est ce qui est recommandé ([réf.](http://etudiant.aujourdhui.fr/etudiant/info/formules-de-politesse.html)).

2/ C'est un message qui semble être adressé à un supérieur hiérarchique et donc la formule de conclusion pourrait ne  pas être tout à fait la plus appropriée : quelque chose comme « salutations distinguées » est peut-être préférable ([réf.](https://www.cadremploi.fr/editorial/conseils/conseils-carriere/detail/article/quelle-formule-de-politesse-utiliser-dans-un-mail-professionnel.html)) ou mieux « Je vous prie de croire, Monsieur, à ma considération distinguées ». À vous de juger.